# How to declare some extern variables in a namespace in a header file

Tags: c++, linker-errors, declaration, definition, extern

I've tried to split my c++ code in multiple files so that it can be cleaner but when I try to test it with building it, I get LNK2005 error.

## GlobalVariables.h

```
#pragma once
#include"ConsolePanel.h"

namespace GlobalVariables {
    extern ConsolePanel CP;

    extern size_t mainDatasetSize = 0;
    extern time_t finishTime;
    extern long double* mainDataset;
    extern long double sum;
    extern int* result;
    extern double resultValue = 0;
    extern bool isThreadsFinished = false;
}
```

## SourceFile1.cpp

```
#include"GlobalVariables.h"
.
.
.
```

## SourceFile2.cpp

```
#include"GlobalVariables.h"
.
.
.
```

I want to use the globalVariables in two seperate files but looks like I can't include the header file in two source files.

Comment: What is the exact error message that you get?

Comment: Not clean enough, good code should not have any globals because they end up being an implicit interface between unrelated bits of code. Define an abstract baseclass (or classes) with getters and create a class (or classes) implementing it (them). Then pass that interface to the pieces of code that may access that information. This pattern is called dependency injection (and its benefits are described in many places). It also makes your code unit-testable (globals are killing for that)

Comment: You really should watch : [Value Semantics: Safety, Independence, Projection, & Future of Programming - Dave Abrahams CppCon 22](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QthAU-t3PQ4). Specialy from 2:51

Comment: You are initializing the variables, so allocating the variables in all units where you include the headers, and so you have a conflict.

Comment: This question's shown code fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre]. Because of that it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You need to [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part, this includes any ancillary information, like any input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: An extern variable must be declared with `extern'` **and** must not receive any init value. Here some variable are declared, but some are defined (like `mainDatasetSize`). You cannot define a variable in a header file.

Comment: It's never too soon to stop using global variables.

Comment: @molbdnilo That's a good summary of my point ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the header

```
namespace GlobalVariables {
    extern ConsolePanel CP;

    extern size_t mainDatasetSize = 0;
    extern time_t finishTime;
    extern long double* mainDataset;
    extern long double sum;
    extern int* result;
    extern double resultValue = 0;
    extern bool isThreadsFinished = false;
}
```

you declared but not defined the following variables with external linkage: `CP`, `finishTime`, `mainDataset`, `sum`, `result`.  You need to define them in some cpp file by placing their declaration without the linkage specifier `extern`. Otherwise they will be undefined.

On the other hand, these variables `mainDatasetSize`, `resultValue`, `isThreadsFinished` were declared and defined because they have initializers. As the header is included in more than one compilation unit then the compiler will issue an error that the variables are redefined. Again you should define them in some cpp file removing their initializers in declarations in the header.  There is no need to initialize them explicitly except for readability because by default they in any case will be zero-initialized.

Pay attention to that in general it is a bad idea to have so many global variables.

Comment: thank you for the answer. just a small detail you should have told me to declare them in the namespace again, I figured it out on my own.

Comment: @FaridG I did not mean to redeclare them in the global namespace.:)